# Как отправить сигнал CTRL+C подпроцессу работающему в потоке python?

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.x, subprocess

Пытаюсь модифицировать существующий код.

В потоке запускается подпроцесс, внешняя программа. Мне необходимо из функции перезапустить эту программу. То есть остановить её, отправив `ctrl + c`, затем обратно поместить в поток. Как это сделать?

Фрагмент запуска внешней программы привожу ниже:

```py
rtl_thread=threading.Thread(
    target=lambda: subprocess.Popen("rtl_sdr", shell=True),
    args=()
)
rtl_thread.start()
```

Полная оригинальная версия кода:

```py
# Start rtl thread
if os.system("csdr 2> /dev/null") == 32512: # check for csdr
    print "[openwebrx-main] You need to install \"csdr\" to run OpenWebRX!\n"
    return

if os.system("nmux --help 2> /dev/null") == 32512: # check for nmux
    print "[openwebrx-main] You need to install an up-to-date version of \"csdr\" that contains the \"nmux\" tool to run OpenWebRX! Please upgrade \"csdr\"!\n"
    return

if cfg.start_rtl_thread:
    nmux_bufcnt = nmux_bufsize = 0

    while nmux_bufsize < cfg.samp_rate / 4:
        nmux_bufsize += 4096

    while nmux_bufsize * nmux_bufcnt < cfg.nmux_memory * 1e6:
        nmux_bufcnt += 1

    if nmux_bufcnt == 0 or nmux_bufsize == 0: 
        print "[openwebrx-main] Error: nmux_bufsize or nmux_bufcnt is zero. These depend on nmux_memory and samp_rate options in config_webrx.py"
        return

    print "[openwebrx-main] nmux_bufsize = %d, nmux_bufcnt = %d" % (nmux_bufsize, nmux_bufcnt)

    cfg.start_rtl_command += "| nmux --bufsize %d --bufcnt %d --port %d --address 127.0.0.1" % (nmux_bufsize, nmux_bufcnt, cfg.iq_server_port)

    rtl_thread=threading.Thread(
        target=lambda: subprocess.Popen(cfg.start_rtl_command, shell=True),
        args=()
    )
    rtl_thread.start()

    print "[openwebrx-main] Started rtl_thread: " + cfg.start_rtl_command
```

Comment: Под ctrl + c, я так понимаю ты просто процесс прервать хочешь? На какой системе запускаешь код? Linux, Windows?

Comment: Да, я хочу просто прервать процесс запущеный в потоке. Основной процесс не трогать, так как я из него планирую снова вызвать  rtl_thread=threading.Thread(
    target=lambda: subprocess.Popen("rtl_sdr", shell=True),
    args=()
)
rtl_thread.start()  
Работает это всё под Debian (raspbian), Linux

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю зачем строить конструкцию Thread + lambda + Popen.
Просто можно запустить:

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(cfg.start_rtl_command, shell=True)
```

Popen создает отдельный процесс с бегущей программой.
Потом убить процесс по необходимости:

```
process1.kill()
```

И перезапустить при первой командой.

Comment: Запуск процесса таким образом работает, а вот остановить не получается. Вылетает с ошибкой. Пока разбираюсь в чём причина.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+C это сигнал SIGTERM, который посылает terminate()

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    cfg.start_rtl_command, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
    shell=False
)
process.terminate()
```